# How to turn a config.ru file into a single Rack application?

Tags: ruby, rack

I have a config.ru file that is starting to have duplicate code:

```
map '/route1' do
  run SampleApp.new
end

map '/route2' do
  run SampleApp.new
end
```

I would like to turn this config.ru file into its own Rack application so that all I have to do is:

```
map '/' do
  run MyApp.new
end
```

What is the correct way to create your own Rack application? Specifically, how can I create a class so that I can use the `map` method within my class to define a bunch of routes?

---

Solution:

Here is a working solution:

```
class MyApp

  def initialize
    @app = Rack::Builder.new do
      # copy contents of your config.ru into this block
      map '/route1' do
        run SampleApp.new
      end

      map '/route2' do
        run SampleApp.new
      end
    end
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

I tried this before, but couldn't get it to work because I was trying to pass instance variables to the `map` blocks. For example:

```
def initialize
  @sample_app = SampleApp.new
  @app = Rack::Builder.new do
    map '/route1' do
      run @sample_app   # will not work
    end
  end
end
```

The reason this will not work is because the block being passed to `map` is being [evaluated in the context of a `Rack::Builder` instance](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/builder.rb#L51).

However, it will work if I pass a local variable:

```
def initialize
  sample_app = SampleApp.new
  @app = Rack::Builder.new do
    map '/route1' do
      run sample_app   # will work
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Just check for the request path in your `#call` method and add conditional statements

Comment: @injekt can you provide an example of what that would look like?

Comment: check my example in my answer, I can add more if it helps but that's the most basic

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The DSL used in `config.ru` is defined in [`Rack::Builder`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/master/lib/rack/builder.rb). When using a `config.ru`, contents of the file are passed to an instance of `Builder` to create the Rack app. You can do this directly yourself in code.

For example, you can take the contents of your existing `config.ru`, and create a new class from it:

```
require 'rack'

class MyApp

  def initialize
    @app = Rack::Builder.new do
      # copy contents of your config.ru into this block
      map '/route1' do
        run SampleApp.new
      end

      map '/route2' do
        run SampleApp.new
      end
    end
  end

  def call(env)
    @app.call(env)
  end
end
```

You need the `call` method so that your class is a Rack app, but you can just forward the request on to the app you create with `Builder`. Then you can create your new `config.ru` that uses your new app:

```
require './my_app'

run MyApp.new
```

Comment: This is pretty much what I am trying to do, and in fact, already tried this very thing. The problem I ran into was I wanted to pass instance variables from my class into the map blocks, but that didn't work because they are being evaluated in the context of a new `Rack::Builder` instance. Do you know of a way that I could subclass `Rack::Builder` so that I don't have to instantiate a `Rack::Builder` instance?

Comment: @Andrew I’m not sure subclassing is the way to go, since `Rack::Builder` recursively creates [instances of itself with `self.class`](https://github.com/rack/rack/blob/1.4.1/lib/rack/builder.rb#L141) and I don’t think you want to get in the way of that.

Comment: @Andrew One posible way to avoid the block being evaluated in the context of the `Builder` would be to create the builder object first, and then explicitly call the DSL methods on that object, e.g. `builder = Rack::Builder.new` followed by `builder.map '/route1' do ...` etc. You could even [push this idea a bit further using the `forwardable` module](https://gist.github.com/3126013) if you want to keep the “plain” DSL methods.

Answer (score 4):

Here is a *really* basic example. You should probably look into `Rack::Response` for handling the response rather than building it yourself, but it gives you a good idea of how basic Rack middleware works:

```
class MyApp
  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)
    headers = { 'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }

    case request.path
    when '/'
      [200, headers, ["You're at the root url!"]]
    when '/foo'
      [200, headers, ["You're at /foo!"]]
    else
      [404, headers, ["Uh oh, path not found!"]]
    end
  end
end
```

---

EDIT:

Mapping multiple Rack apps into one:

```
class RootApp
  def call(env)
    [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, ['Main root url']]
  end
end

class FooApp
  def call(env)
    [200, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, ['Foo app url!']]
  end
end

class MyApp
  def initialize
    @apps = {}
  end

  def map(route, app)
    @apps[route] = app
  end

  def call(env)
    request = Rack::Request.new(env)

    if @apps[request.path]
      @apps[request.path].call(env)
    else
      [404, {'Content-Type' => 'text/html' }, ['404 not found']]
    end
  end
end

app = MyApp.new
app.map '/', RootApp.new
app.map '/foo', FooApp.new

run app
```

Comment: hmm...that is helpful. However, I need to run a Rack application at each path defined. So I don't think this solution is going to work. Do you know how I could do that?

Comment: that is a getting closer. However, matt's answer is a little closer to what I am looking for. See [my comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11512641/how-to-turn-a-config-ru-file-into-a-single-rack-application#comment15215304_11513098) on his answer

Answer (score 3):

How about using URLMap?

```
app = Rack::URLMap.new(
  "/path1" => Path1App.new,
  "/path2" => Path2App.new
)

run app
```

Answer (score 0):

I do this:

```
class MyApp 
  def call(env)
    @env = env

    # REQUEST_URI is still encoded; split before decoding to allow encoded slashes
    @path = env['REQUEST_URI'].split('/')

    # REQUEST_URI starts with a slash, so delete blank first element
    @path.delete_at(0)

    @path.each_index do |i|
      @path[i]= CGI.unescape(@path[i])
    end

    route()
  end
end
```

And then `route()` can do whatever it wants to route the request, e.g.:

```
class MyApp 
  def route
    m = @env['REQUEST_METHOD']
    @section = @path.shift

    if not @section
      home()
    elsif @section == 'route1' and m == 'GET'
      route1()
    # else ...
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: I would recommend `Rack::Request` over splitting up the info yourself. It'll handle all the load and look much nicer.

Comment: @injekt Huh, I just looked through [the docs](http://rack.rubyforge.org/doc/classes/Rack/Request.html) and don't see how that would come into play here. I use it for the `params()` method when I need to process a query string or POST form data, but I don't see any methods that would help with parsing and routing the path...